# Why ToyVpn with TCP really really slow compare to UDP

Tags: android, c++, sockets, tcp

I am trying ToyVpn with Android VPNService

This is the sample code for server side.
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ToyVpn/server/linux/ToyVpnServer.cpp

In this example, it use SOCK_DGRAM.

I try change it to use SOCK_STREAM. I change a few code to handle TCP connection, for example using listen() & accept().

It connect and working fine, however it is really slow.

I know UDP is faster than TCP for various reason. But it is unreasonably slow.

For example: it took 10 sec to open a webpage using UDP, however TCP took 1 minute and even more.

I try to set TCP NO DELAY but it still slow.

Is anyone know the reason ?

Thanks